# Copy & Paste Cell Value "X" amount of times then loop to next row

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

Details:

1. Copy cell value in column D IF YR value is 1, paste starting in column G
2. This repeats in each row for counter # of times IE if counter is 5, copy & paste cell value from G to K
3. Once counter is expired, move to next row and repeat process

Screen Shot of Excel
[image]

```
Dim StartRow As Byte
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim ii As Integer
Dim cnt As Integer

StartRow = 3
LastRow = Range("B3").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1

For i = StartRow To LastRow
    cnt = Range("C" & i).Value
    For ii = 1 To cnt
        If Range("B" & StartRow) = 1 Then
            Range("D" & StartRow).Copy
            Range("B" & StartRow).End(xlToRight).Offset(0, ii + 2).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
        End If
    Next ii
Next i
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How to copy & paste multiple times based on a counter value, followed by looping through several rows (only doing this if YR 1).  Mazaffer GALATA's code seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
Dim StartRow As Byte
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim ii As Integer
Dim cnt As Integer
Dim limitCol As Integer

StartRow = 3
LastRow = Range("B3").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1

For i = StartRow To LastRow
    If (CInt(Range("B" & i)) = 1) Then
        cnt = Range("C" & i).Value
        limitCol = cnt + 6
        For ii = 7 To limitCol
            Cells(i, ii) = Range("D" & i).Value
        Next ii
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: This seems to work OK based on some back-testing.  Thank you.